# Badge appStore notification doesn't update

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store

I've published my app to newer version recently. I know app store got delay updating it's badge.

but how long usually App Store (application) update my device application updates on its badge?

I hope doesn't confuse anyone. :)

Comment: Are you sure it does update the badge without the user actually opening the app? I've never noticed the badge updating itself, but I've noticed multiple times that it updates once I've opened the App Store app itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything I read says that iOS checks for updates to installed apps when the AppStore App is opened. There may be a process that checks occasionally (I didn't find anything suggesting that this does happen though).

Is there any integral reason for you to be pushing the update to your users (i.e. security issue fixed or major performance error resolved)? You could have your app check somewhere for a signal that an update is available (probably on the web). This check could be performed everytime your app is opened (maybe even in the background if you do it within some allowable background process).